# call a sql function stored in a separate db server from a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sql-function

I have a SQL function stored in a db server and want to call it from a stored procedure in a separate sever.Is that possible? In case it is possible, please provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call stored procedures/functions or simply call some sql queries from remote database you can use DATABASE LINKS. To create such database link you can call:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK database.name.com
CONNECT TO scheme_you_want_to_connect_to IDENTIFIED BY password_to_the_scheme
USING service_name;
```

When you create database link, you should be able to call the procedures like this (assuming you have sufficient grants):

```
mySchema.myPackage.myProcedure('some', 'params', 'you', 'want', 'to', 'pass')@database.name.com
```

I'm sure you will find lots of other examples in the web.